# Finding subscriber counts where End Date and Start Date are in same month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get counts of subscribers who terminate and re-enroll in the same month when the Termination reason is 'xxx' for past 12 months in a row.

[image: Example]

In the above example, subscriber '1245' has been terminated for 'xxx' reason but re-enrolled again in the same month. I want counts of how many times this happens month by month for last n number of months.

I tried below code to get PersonIDs but having trouble getting counts in a month.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID FROM Membership A

INNER JOIN (SELECT StartYrMo FROM Membership) B

ON A.EndYrMo = B.StartYrMo

WHERE A.TermReason = 'xxx'

ORDER BY PersonID
```

**EDIT** There is more to it. I want all the PersonIds who does so for at least 6 months in a row. Meaning: Person 'A' is terminated due to 'xxx' reason in 201901. 'A' is again terminated due to same 'xxx' reason in 201902 through 201908 which is minimum of 6 months. I want Ids of everyone who does this.

Comment: Assuming this is SQL Server. You need a `GROUP BY` for starters. Add on the JOIN `AND A.PersonID = B.PersonID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.PersonID FROM Membership A

INNER JOIN Membership B ON A.PersonID = B.PersonID
INNER JOIN Membership C ON A.PersonID = C.PersonID
INNER JOIN Membership D ON A.PersonID = D.PersonID

WHERE A.TermReason = 'xxx'
AND   B.TermReason = 'xxx'
AND   C.TermReason = 'xxx'
AND   D.TermReason = 'xxx'

AND   B.StartMonth = A.EndMonth
-- following assumes minimum date in your dataset is '201101'.
-- '+ 89' returns '201201' instead of '201113' when EndMonth is '201112'.
AND   C.StartMonth = CASE WHEN A.EndMonth IN ('201112', '201212', '201312', '201412', '201512', '201612', '201712', '201812', '201912')
                     THEN A.EndMonth + 89 ELSE A.EndMonth + 1 END
AND   D.StartMonth = CASE WHEN A.EndMonth IN ('201112', '201212', '201312', '201412', '201512', '201612', '201712', '201812', '201912', '201111', '201211', '201311', '201411', '201511', '201611', '201711', '201811', '201911')
                     THEN A.EndMonth + 90 ELSE A.EndMonth + 2 END
-- repeat for additional months as needed.

ORDER BY PersonID
```

To reduce redundancy, this code only looks at 3 consecutive months. If it does not return any results, then you do not have to worry about writing additional lines of codes for other months (if it is a one time request). Because if there are no one in 3 consecutive months, then there shall be no one in 6 consecutive months. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To get resubscribed persons:

```
select m2.PersonID, m2.StartMonth as ResubscriptionMonth
            from Membership m1 inner join Membership m2
            on m1.PersonID = m2.PersonID
            where m1.TermReason = 'xxx' and m1.EndMonth = m2.StartMonth
```

To get numbers by month:

```
select Resubscibtions.ResubscriptionMonth, Count(*)
from (
        select m2.PersonID, m2.StartMonth as ResubscriptionMonth
        from Membership m1 inner join Membership m2
        on m1.PersonID = m2.PersonID
        where m1.TermReason = 'xxx' and m1.EndMonth = m2.StartMonth) as Resubscibtions 
group by Resubscibtions.ResubscriptionMonth
```

Comment: First part works perfect. Just needed to add DISTINCT to PersonID because of the way my data is present. Will get back to second part soon. Thanks!

Comment: If that is the answer You are looking for mark it as answered :) If You got any other question please let me know in the comment.

Comment: Thanks! Jacek. I edited my question. Appreciate your help while I simultaneously work on it!